# How to define multi-variable polynomial using sequence?

Tags: polynomials

In his [Basic Algebra](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~aknapp/), Knapp defines one-variable polynomials using sequences.

I am curious to find out the definition of multi-variable polynomials by using sequences.

Comment: Please tell us the definition by Knapp of polynomials using sequences.

Comment: You can download the book, then read the related section of chapter 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polynomial in $n$ indeterminates over a ring $R$  may be defined as the set of all multi-sequences $(a_{\nu})_{\nu\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $a_\nu\in R$ such that all but finitely many $a_\nu$ vanish.